# If Spark Driver fails inside YARN application master, what will be its consequences?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

There would be certain scenarios when spark driver inside YARN application master (when launched in YARN cluster mode) may fail. Hence, In this case job will also fail. Is there a way which will guarantee exactly once and at the same time restart the driver automatically without user intervention?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: By default I think yarn tries twice.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But can you please enlighten me on how does it guarantee exactly once?